# Docker "hello-world" is giving "process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2016, docker-ee

We have just uninstalled Docker Community Edition and installed Enterprise Edition on a Windows Server 2016 System [as per these steps](https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/#use-a-script-to-install-docker-ee).

On reaching the last step which is to test a hello-world container we are receiving the following error:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: failed to register layer: re-exec
>   error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\e345ad40cc8f7d073f62501b7445d42d677889c04b2c6fe0963ea6e092b52f95\UtilityVM:
>   **The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.**

We are seeing lots of examples on SO related to other types of applications giving this error but not Docker.

How might we fix this?

Comment: Does a reboot clear the error?  Have you tried either disabling your antivirus temporarily?  Have you tried using Process Explorer to view any open handles on that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue related to Symantec Endpoint Protection(SEP) clashing with Docker.

SEP needs to be upgraded to version 14 RU1 and several files need execution privileges.

Symantec posted a fix here: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH246815.html which we have tried and worked.